# Unable to publish VSIX extension when the VSIX author name doesn't match the publisher name

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

I own a VSIX extension that's been around for 10+ years: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidEbbo.RazorGenerator.

In the vsixmanifest, the identity looks like this:

```
<Identity Id="2FD58EB3-29A2-40A3-BE17-C024CA9A17A2" Version="1.13.0" Language="en-US" Publisher="RazorGenerator contributors" />
```

This has never been a problem before, but now when I try to publish it, it fails with:

```
Publisher display name (David Ebbo) in Marketplace and Author name (RazorGenerator contributors) in the extension need to be the same to publish the extension.
```

It looks like it's now enforcing that the Author name needs to match my display name (David Ebbo).

Why would it do that, and how can I work around it?

Comment: Update the publisher name?

Comment: @ErikEJ this doesn't work, as it ends up saying that the VSIX ID is already in use. It seems changing publisher name changes the identity. Also, I'd like to keep the current name.

Comment: Call Mads Kristensen 

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was being stupid and doing the wrong thing in the Marketplace site (which is rather confusing).

Specifically, I was using the 'New Extension' button, while the correct thing to do is click on the '...' next to the extension name, and then choose Edit.